# Android metadata with manifest file - nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, metadata

I am attempting to access metadata for an activity from the manifest file.

The manifest looks like this :

```
    <activity
        android:name="co.uk.benbun.nvrrclubapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:value="newstag" android:name="NEWS"></meta-data>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The code to access it, looks like this :

```
    try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
        String myApiKey = bundle.getString("NEWS");
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("metadata", "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        feedTag = "NEWS";
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e("metadata", "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());
        feedTag = "NEWS";
    }
```

When I execute the code I always get the nullPointerException.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_META_DATA) for `PackageManager.GET_META_DATA` says:

> ComponentInfo flag: return the metaData data Bundles that are
>   associated with a component. This applies for any API returning a
>   ComponentInfo subclass.

You are calling `getApplicationInfo()` which returns an `ApplicationInfo` object. `ApplicationInfo` does not inherit from `ComponentInfo`, so this object will not have any meta-data. You need to get the `ActivityInfo` for your `MainActivity` in order to get the meta-data (`ActivityInfo` is a subclass of `ComponentInfo`).

Comment: Although the documentation does explicitly state this is only for ComponentInfo items, it does appear that without it, the ApplicationInfo's metaData Bundle is null.